# How can I get a QObject's children?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt4, qt5

I am trying to get the children of the a `QObject` class and add their data to the parent (see QML example below). However, when I call the following code in the constructor, it returns no children. It appears that the child list has not yet been populated. It works if I place the same code in the `paint()` function, but I need the data earlier than that.

```
MultiGauge::MultiGauge() : 
    QQuickPaintedItem()
{
    QObjectList children = this->children();

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++)
    {
        this->myQList.append(children[i]->metaObject()->className());
    } 
}
```

Here is the QML file

```
MultiGauge {

    height: 125
    width: height
    Limits {
        min: 0
        caution: 1250
        max: 2000
    }
    Limits {
        min: 100
        caution: 200
        max: 300
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Solution:**

```
MultiGauge::componentComplete()
{
    // must call the parent's version of the function first
    QQuickPaintedItem::componentComplete();

    // now we can do what we need to
    QObjectList children = this->children();

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++)
    {
        this->myQList.append(children[i]->metaObject()->className());
    } 
}
```

Comment: I believe there should be no children when the constructor is called for the parent. The children should be added after the parent is constructed.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, but how do I properly capture those afterwards? `childEvent(QChildEvent *event)` does not appear to trigger

Comment: It seems to me that the parent does not know he has children, you have to get them when you need them.

Comment: Try invoking a C++ function from QML from `Component.onCompleted`

Comment: @dtech Thank you. That is the solution that I was looking for.

Comment: @dtech Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delay the iteration until the QML object tree is completed. You can that by using

```
MultiGauge {
  // ...
  Component.onCompleted: doSomeStuff()
}
```

Comment: Works with Widgets and QObject too.